# Блок с контентом не отображается над тенью modal wrap

Tags: html, css, modal

Все темы схожие прочла, но пока ничего так и не нашла.

К modal wrap не тянется блок с контентом. Тень есть, но блок сверху не работает.

```css
.lstran {
    background: url(https://i.postimg.cc/QNz3WN8x/blue-concrete-wall-with-scratches3.png) no-repeat;
    height: 400px;
    width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #383e44;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #000000 inset, 0px 0px 5px #d939576e;
    border: #000000 1px solid;
}

.lstran verh {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}


.lstran verh kart {
    background: #dce4e6;
    box-shadow: 11px 6px 50px #0000002b inset, 5px 3px 9px #8d206a6e;
    padding: 2px 2px 0px 2px;
    width: 180px;
    border-radius: 100px !important;
    position: absolute;
}

.lstran verh kart img {
    border-radius: 100px !important;
    filter: sepia(1) hue-rotate(286deg);
}

.lstran verh inf1 {
    width: 647px;
    height: 190px;
}

.lstran verh inf1 name {
    display: block;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: Bebas Neue;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.lstran verh inf1 tex {
    display: block;
    white-space: break-spaces;
    height: 159px;
    width: 438px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-family: 'Kelly Slab';
    font-size: 14px;
}


.lstran verh inf2 {
    width: 440px;
    height: 190px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    text-align: right!important;
}

.lstran verh inf2 name {
    display: block;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: Bebas Neue;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.lstran verh inf2 tex {
    display: block;
    white-space: break-spaces;
    height: 158px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin-top: 1px;
    font-family: 'Kelly Slab';
    font-size: 11px;
    width: 245px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.lstran niz {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.lstran niz koz {
    background: #ccafba4d;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #ffffff2b inset, 0px 0px 5px #b5bdbf6e;
    border: #00000000 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 183px;
    height: 179px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    font-family: Bebas Neue;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.lstran niz koz a {
    color: #ffe295 !important;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.lstran niz koz img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 119px;
}

.lstran niz koz z {
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Bebas Neue;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: .6px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;}

.lstran niz awa {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Bebas Neue;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: .6px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    background: #dce4e6;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #ffffff2b inset, 0px 0px 5px #b5bdbf6e;
    border: #36363600 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ccafba4d;
    width: 225px;
    height: 180px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
}


.lstran niz awa img {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
}

.lstran niz nagr img {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 4px;
}

.lstran niz nagr z {
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Bebas Neue;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: .6px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;}

.lstran niz koz z {
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Bebas Neue;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: .6px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;}

.lstran niz nagr {
    width: 204px;
    display: flex;
    height: 180px;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow-y: auto;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Bebas Neue;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: .6px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    background: #ccafba4d !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #ffffff2b inset, 0px 0px 5px #b5bdbf6e;
    border: #36363600 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #afbecc4d;
}

.perv {
    /* width: 730px; */
    background: #d4dadc85;
    border: #8795a7 1px solid;
}


.perv zag {
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #ffffff2b inset, 0px 0px 5px #b5bdbf6e;
    background: url(http://forumstatic.ru/files/001b/cb/86/37844.jpg) repeat;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8795a7;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #e8efef;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: raleway;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #76879b;
}


.perv text {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 15px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    letter-spacing: .3px;
}


.face text {
    display: block;
    margin: 15px 20px 0px 20px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    letter-spacing: .3px;
}

.stickytext,.closedatafield{ display:none;}

.reactions-root {display: none;}

.code-box strong.legend a {
    color: #edf0f1 !IMPORTANT;
}

.reveal-modal-bg {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #000000bf;}

.reveal-modal {
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 100px; 
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -300px;
    width: 520px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    padding: 30px 40px 34px;}

.reveal-modal.small     { width: 200px; margin-left: -140px;}
.reveal-modal.medium     { width: 400px; margin-left: -240px;}
.reveal-modal.large     { width: 600px; margin-left: -340px;}
.reveal-modal.xlarge     { width: 800px; margin-left: -440px;}
    
.reveal-modal .close-reveal-modal {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: .5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 11px;
    color: #aaa;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rbga(0,0,0,.6);
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<div id="pers" class="reveal-modal xlarge main container">
<div class='modal_wrap'></div>
<a class="close-reveal-modal">×</a>
</div>
```

Сама страница с контентом:

```html
<div class='pers'> 
<div class="lstran">
<verh>
<kart><img src="картинка"></kart>
<inf1>
<name>ИМЯ</name><br>
<tex><b>Показ 1:</b> текст <br>
<b>Показ 2:</b><br>
текст <br>
</tex>
</inf1>

<inf2>
<name>Об игроке</name><br>
<tex><b>Пишу от:</b>  текст <br>
<b>Доп.инфо:</b> Текст<br>
</tex>
</inf2>
</verh>
<niz>
<koz><z>ТЕКСТ</z>
</koz>

<awa><z>ТЕКСТ</z><br>
</awa>


<nagr>
<center><img src="https://3dicons.sgp1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/v1/dynamic/premium/star-dynamic-premium.png"  title="постописец">
<img src="https://3dicons.sgp1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/v1/dynamic/premium/fire-dynamic-premium.png"  title="активист">
<img src="https://3dicons.sgp1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/v1/dynamic/premium/crow-dynamic-premium.png"  title="лучший эпизод"></center><br>
<center><img src="https://3dicons.sgp1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/v1/dynamic/premium/medal-dynamic-premium.png"  title="лучший пост">
<img src="https://3dicons.sgp1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/v1/dynamic/premium/chat-text-dynamic-premium.png"  title="лучшая цитата">
<img src="https://3dicons.sgp1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/v1/dynamic/premium/mic-dynamic-premium.png"  title="лучший трек"></center></nagr>

</niz>
</div>
</div>
```